# How to set limit for accessing data in heidisql?

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, heidisql, hibernate-native-query

By default, limit of accessing data in Heidi SQL is upto 100000.

SELECT * FROM table*name WHERE columnname='value' and 'column*_name'='value';

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='value'
 and column_name='value' LIMIT 0,1000000;

Comment: What are you planning to do with such a large result set directly in your SQL tool?

Comment: Actually, I want to get data at my Production DB. So, at that time I was only able to access the data having more than 1 Lakh data. That's why I want this query need to be run in Heidi SQL.

Comment: Can you write to a file?

Comment: Sorry, Could you elaborate your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.